# Ureadahead not working on ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: 12.04, lts, ureadahead

I discovered using bootchart that my ureadahead isn't working on ubuntu 12.04lts on a dell inspiron 1545, anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: What did you see that leads you to believe it isn't working?

Comment: In addition to answering neon_overload's question specifically, please provide all the detailed output from bootchart.

Comment: Also, what files exist in your /var/lib/ureadahead/ directory?  This may help determine whether it has got as far as generating the pack files.